# Linux capabilities for java to resolve symbolic links

Tags: centos, symlink, java, capabilities

I run a java program by a non-root user.
The program has to resolve a symlink to the real file name,
but the link is owned by a different non-root user.
I used `setcap` to set capabilities to open root-privileged sockets etc. but when trying to resolve the link using `Files.readSymbolicLink()` I get  `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` exception.

What capabilities allows this?

Details:
Java 8
OS: centos 7

Comment: Does the user have read and execute perms on the directory that contains the symlink?

Comment: Yes. both the file that the link relates to and the directory it is located in are 755

Comment: Not the file that the link relates to, that doesn't matter at all. The directory containing the link itself is what is relevant.

Comment: Got execute permissions: 555